# How to group and return specific permutations of rows in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, permutation

This question is easier with an example.

Suppose table A contains all permutations over two columns for two groups (A,B,C) and (D,E,F):

```
**id1** | **id2**  
A   | B  
A   | C  
B   | A  
B   | C  
C   | A  
C   | B  
D   | E  
D   | F  
E   | D  
E   | F  
F   | D  
F   | E
```

I want to group the rows and get unique permutations in SQL:

**query result**

```
id1 | id2  
A   | B  
A   | C  
D   | E  
D   | F
```

or

```
id1 | id2  
B   | A  
B   | C  
E   | D  
E   | F
```

(The common letter for the group in the first column is a requirement)

Comment: what about `B,C` and `E,F`? why are they excluded?

Comment: The real use case behind this is snapping of linestrings (geometry). In the example, when snapping is done independently for each row, B,C and E,F will either create redundant snapping, or will introduce errors.

Comment: what's your dbms?

Comment: So it doesn't matter if you start w/ {A, B, or C} or {D, E, or F} Just so long as duplication doesn't exist of any set?

Comment: (A, B, C) and (D, E, F) are completely independent of each other, yes. They are different intersections of linestrings, and does not have anything to do with each other.

Comment: dbms: PostgreSQL, SQL Server and Oracle. If there are better ways in any of these databases, I will  use of them. :)

Comment: Is AB equivalent to BA?

Comment: @SandPiper: As long as you obey the requirement to keep the common letter in the first column, it is. I.e. either AB and AC, or BA and BC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we can assume Common Table Expressions (CTEs) exist for your Database (Oracle, Postgresql and SQL Server could all use the 1st option)

This assumes returning the set with the smallest ID1 first is acceptable.  If you want the one with the largest ID1 , simply change `<` to `>`.

If you want a "Middle" value which could be of varying sizes... that would take more work.

```
WITH T2 as (SELECT * FROM t WHERE ID1 < ID2)
SELECT * 
FROM t2 
WHERE ID1 not in (Select ID2 FROM t2)
```

If not...

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM t 
      WHERE ID1 < ID2)
WHERE ID1 not in (SELECT ID2 
                  FROM (SELECT * 
                        FROM t 
                        WHERE ID1 < ID2)A )
```

though you could use a not exists  instead of the IN... but I was in a hurry...

Now if you just have a table of the set data along with a SetNo...

```
with T (ID1, SetNo) as (
SELECT 'A',1 from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',1 from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',1 from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'D',2 from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'E',2 from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'F',2 from dual )

SELECT A.ID1, B.ID1 as ID2 
FROM (Select MIN(ID1) ID1, SetNO from t group by SetNo) A
CROSS JOIN T B
WHERE  B.ID1 <> A.ID1 and A.SetNo = B.SetNo
```

Comment: Thanks - this works well :) (I can not hardcode the values)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the first column is always the lower value. `UNION` removes duplicates:

```
select id1, id2
from
(
    select id1, id2 from a where id1 <= id2
    union
    select id2, id1 from a where id1 > id2
)
where id1 in ('A', 'D')
```

Executes as:

```
SQL>select id1, id2
SQL&from
SQL&(
SQL&    select id1, id2 from a where id1 <= id2
SQL&    union
SQL&    select id2, id1 from a where id1 > id2
SQL&)
SQL&where id1 in ('A', 'D');
id1 id2
=== ===
A   B
A   C
D   E
D   F

                  4 rows found
```

Comment: gets 12 results shouldn't it be 4?

Comment: @xQbert, I get 6 rows.

Comment: Better, I just don't like the hardcoding.

Comment: @xQbert, to be honest, neither do I... (Have to work too!)